# Can't put a value to textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox

I trying to make a function, which will put a string value into a first empty textbox. 
For example: I have 5 textboxs. `Textbox0.val()="1"`, `Textbox1.val()="2"`, `Textbox2.val()=nullOrEmpty`, `Textbox3.val()="3"`. I want to put string value to `textbox2`.

This is my code:

```
function textb() {
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt($("#lengthClub").val()) ; i++) {
        var t = $("#textbox" + i);
        if ( t.value() == null) {
            j = i;
            break;
        } 
    }
    return j;
}

$(document).ready(function () {       
    $("#button0").click(function () {
    // $("#textbox0").value += "1";
    $("#textbox"+textb()).val("1");
});
```

But program puts "1" only into `textbox0`. Can you help me?

Comment: check my solution in this don't compare with null compare with  empty string

Comment: `if(!t.val().length)` you could want to trim it btw: `if(!$.trim(t.val()).length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. Textboxes always have a value of at least an empty string - `""`; therefore you cannot check for null.
2. `.value()` is not a method. You should be using `.val()`.

The following code should work for you:

```
if (t.val() == "") {
    j = i;
    break;
}
```

You most likely got confused on the second mistake with the `.value` option of a javascript object. If you ever need to get the javascript object from the jQuery object, you can use the following:

```
var t = $("#textbox" + i)[0];
var t2 = $("#textbox" + i).get(0);

if (t.value == "") {
    j = i;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if ( t.value() == null) {
```

to

```
if ( t.val() == null) {
```

Comment: No. He just put "1" only into textbox0. That's all.

Comment: @user2037334 Look at the other answers, most likley the problem `t.val()==""`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( t.val() == "") {//  t.value() change in t.val()
                j = i;
                break;
            }
```

reference [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)